# Удаление QDialog с помощью delete

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется следующий кусочек кода:

```
void AddOrderWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
   // Вызываем окно
   ModuleDeteils *window = new ModuleDeteils(socket, account, this);
   qDebug() << window;
   ...
   ...
   window->exec();
   ...
   ...
   delete window;
   qDebug() << window;
}
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то после `delete` объект по указателю `window` должен быть удален, а в `qDebug()` выведет "0". Но происходит следующие: 
Первый `qDebug()` выдает

> ModuleDeteils(0x190fd540, name="ModuleDeteils");

Второй`qDebug()` выдает

> QObject(0x190fd540, name="ModuleDeteils");

Если на кнопку нажать повторно, то получим другой адрес:

> ModuleDeteils(0x190fd800, name="ModuleDeteils"); 
>   QObject(0x190fd800,
>   name="ModuleDeteils");

При всем этом я точно знаю, что вызывается одно и тоже окно, т.к. специально перед закрытием окна отключаю один из виджетов с помощью метода `setDisabled(true)`. 
Почему окно не удаляется при вызове `delete`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... после `delete` ... `qDebug()` выведет "0"

Оператор `delete` делает указатель некорректным, но не зануляет его (так как сам указатель передаётся в функцию удаления по значению). Вы должны либо вручную присвоить ему `NULL` (или `nullptr` в C++11), либо просто не использовать.

> ... Второй `qDebug()` выдает ...

Добро пожаловать в мир неопределённого поведения.

То, что объект как бы остаётся доступным по старому адресу — всего лишь иллюзия. Вызвана она тем, что диспетчер памяти Windows (как, впрочем, и Linux) по умолчанию ничего не очищает при освобождении, а просто помечает соответствующую область как свободную; поэтому память, занимаемая объектом, продолжает хранить старые данные. Однако эта область может быть спокойно перекрыта данными другого объекта при очередном выделении памяти в куче.

Почему поведение неопределённое? Да потому что стандарт прямо это говорит относительно обращения к указателям, над которыми был выполнен `delete` или `free()`.

Comment: "Оператор delete делает указатель некорректным, но не зануляет его" - спасибо, тут понятно. А что по поводу высвобождения памяти можете сказать? Почему не высвобождается память? И по чему тогда в указателе уже с другим адресом открывается старый объект? Спасибо.

Comment: @Madisson, дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Открывал и закрывал окно несколько раз. Открывал и закрывал родительские окна. Диспетчер задач показывает,что память освобождается, но окно которое должно было быть удалено, все равно открывается снова и снова :)

Comment: @Madisson, добавьте в вопрос код из конструктора и деструктора.

Comment: @Madisson (бросил клич в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c), но там без кода, о котором вы говорите, тоже помочь не смогли).

Comment: В общем проблема видимо была в креаторе. Сегодня запустил код - все работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

То что вы delete указатель ещё не значит что ему присвоиться нулевое значение. Для такого поведения надо делать всякие "умные" указатели которых в Qt много. Можете начать с QPointer.

Ещё мне хотелось бы предостеречь от подобных приёмов. В данном случае надо не создавать объект в динамической памяти (оператором new ). А просто создать локальную переменную - объект класса.

Правильно :

```
void AddOrderWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
   // Вызываем окно
   ModuleDeteils window(socket, account, this);
   qDebug() << window;
   ...
   ...
   window.exec();
   ...
   ...
 //  delete window; Здесь не нужно
   qDebug() << window;
}
```

Здесь объект самостоятельно убьётся в конце области видимости. И не будет риска что какой нибудь дилетант по ошибке снесет "delete".